# Get $store data in ~/plugins/axios

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm new with VueJs, I'm finding best way to get $store data in ~/plugins/axios in VueJS in order to use it for APIs. But some errors occur. Hope your helps

**~/plugins/axios.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '~/store'

var api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + store.state.token}
})

export default api
```

**Errors:**

`Issues: Can't tranmit store in to axios.create, so store is not defined`

**My ~/Store.JS:**

```
const AuthenticationStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      token: null
    },
    mutations: {
      SET_TOKEN: function (state, token) {
        state.token = token
        instance.defaults.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
      }
    },
    actions: {
      ....
    }
  })
}

const createStore = () => {
  return AuthenticationStore
}
export { AuthenticationStore }

export default createStore
```

Error:
`Cannot read property 'token' of undefined` in `'headers': {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + store.state.token}`

Comment: You can use my new [package](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/vue-plugin-axios/graphs/traffic). It makes it easy to put a token and call methods easily.

Answer (score 1):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '../store'

var api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/',
  headers: {'Authorization': 'JWT ' + store.state.token}
})

export default api
```

You need to import your store.

If you are using `Nuxt.js` the default store will be in classic mode. It will export a function that create a vuex store.

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import mutations from './mutations'

const createStore = () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      counter: 0
    },
    mutations
  })
}

export default createStore
```

So you can fix the new error by switching to modules mode https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#modules-mode.

Or edit your `store/index.js` to the following strucutre

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import mutations from './mutations'
cosnt store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      counter: 0
    },
    mutations
  })
const createStore = () => {
  return store
}

export { store }
export default createStore
```

and change the import statement in `~plugins/axios.js` to `import { store } from '../store'`

Comment: Please tell me import store from what? Token state in localstorage, bro ^^

Comment: Does $store refers to vuex store? I am assuming you have similar app structure like [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/counter) . Then you import this `store.js` to get data from it.

Comment: $store refers to vuex store --> That rights. I use NuxtJS

Comment: Not work. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`

Comment: I solve your first error which is a import missing error. The new error is about the imported vuex store instance don't have `state` field.You might also include your source code in your store folder.

Comment: Nuxt.js default export from `store/index.js` is a function. So `import store from '../store'` will not contain `state` since its a function.

Comment: I fix as you type in NuxtJS. But it doesnt work! Please take a look my code updated above !!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in your mutation:

```
{
  SET_TOKEN: function (state, token) {
    state.token = token;        
    Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] =
        (token ? ('JWT ' + token) : '');
}
```

Every time you set a token in a mutation you update your default token, so you won't have to set it in each request you do. Could do this in an action as well.

That's assuming you have your `axios` available globally via `this.axios`. There's a [VueAxios](https://github.com/imcvampire/vue-axios) library just for that. Make sure you do this in your entry js file (`main.js` probably):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
```

That way you'll never have to import your store or axios when you need to make a request. Your typical request would look like this:

```
this.axios.get('URL', {data}, {options});
```

Comment: How can I do this? I updated my code with mutations!

Comment: Updated the answer.